# Linux incoming/outgoing packets modifying module

Tags: linux

Can anybody give me a link to manual or sample of linux kernel driver, which can modify incoming/outgoing packets from/to specified ip-port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I thought that myself, and almost answered it, but is that, specifically, a *linux kernel driver*? In the same vein as `CONFIG_INET`?